# alt+click doesn't mark a message as unread on slack webapp

Tags: slack

From slack's Keyboard shortcut menu (`ctrl+/`):

```
Mark a message as unread --- Alt and click message
```

But this doesn't work :(

When I alt+click I get a clutched hand icon.

Running ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

`alt+super+click` works.

The problem is that alt+click is grabbed by the OS.

See more info here: https://askubuntu.com/q/521423/13330

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works for me!